# How to validate a word in python?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pyenchant, enchant

I have a list in Python like this:

```
`list = ['thatCreation', 'happeningso', '’', 'comebecause',]
```

Question :

I want specific words:

```
For e.g. -> 'thatCreation' -> 'that', 'creation'
            'happeningso' -> 'happening', 'so'
            'comebeacause' -> 'come', 'because' `
```

Thanks in advance for solving it in python.

Comment: What is the logic of this transformations?

Comment: Do have a list of the specific words you want to find?

Comment: I know the logic that how to get invalid english words from the paragraph, but I don't know the logic of this mentioned problem.

Comment: What should "haventour" be "validated" to? "haven tour" or "havent our"?

Comment: I want to extract that one word and want to make a valid word. I want to make 'thatCreation'  a valid two words that are'that' and 'creation'.  - @drops

Comment: how do you get this list ? Maybe you should change code which create this list and add spaces between words when you create list.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but words in my list can be validated, the 'haventour' type of problem is a next step, but I want to validate those words which are possible. - @Sayse

Comment: It doesn't seem like you do want to validate them, it looks as though you're only interested in getting someone else to validate them for you. [ask].

Comment: I got a whole paragraph, and there are no other issues in my program, and I am doing a project on NLP and for that, I have to validate such words. - @furas

Comment: No, it is not like that, I am trying to do it for 2 days, and because it was not possible for me to solve it, so I have asked here. - @Sayse

Comment: how do you get this paragraph ? Do you change somthing in this paragram ? ie. replace `\n` with empty string?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to take words merged together in camel case and break it apart. There is a great algorithm called [Viterbi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm) that does this really well.

I can't explain the magic behind it, but I implemented it in my program recently and it works really well. My understanding is it calculates the probability of each word and splits on that. **This algorithm can split words in any case.**

```
def word_prob(word): return dictionary[word] / total
def words(text): return re.findall('[a-z]+', text.lower()) 
dictionary = Counter(words(open(words_path).read()))
max_word_length = max(map(len, dictionary))
total = float(sum(dictionary.values()))

def viterbi_segment(text):
    probs, lasts = [1.0], [0]
    for i in range(1, len(text) + 1):
        prob_k, k = max((probs[j] * word_prob(text[j:i]), j)
                        for j in range(max(0, i - max_word_length), i))
        probs.append(prob_k)
        lasts.append(k)
    words = []
    i = len(text)
    while 0 < i:
        words.append(text[lasts[i]:i])
        i = lasts[i]
    words.reverse()
    return words, probs[-1]

sentence = ' '.join(viterbi_segment('thatCreation'.lower())[0])
print('sentence: {0}'.format(sentence))
word = ''.join(a.capitalize() for a in split('([^a-zA-Z0-9])', sentence)
       if a.isalnum())
print('word: {0}'.format(word[0].lower() + word[1:]))
```

You need a dictionary of a ton of words, there are multiple out there, but I used:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/first20hours/google-10000-english/master/google-10000-english-no-swears.txt

and updated it with new words that it didn't have.

Comment: happeningso isn't camel case.

Comment: Thanks for helping me but not all words are camel cases than what should I do?. - @bittermelonman

Comment: @RohanPatel This doesn't need camelcase. In my implementation, all words are capitalized, so yourname-> your name. You can then use .title() or .upper/lower() from Python for your use case.

Comment: Your given code was right but there were some issues, which lead to wrong o/p - @bittermelonman. But thanks a lot for helping me and giving a different view on it.

Comment: @RohanPatel can you elaborate on why it doesn't work? I have it working in my application. Maybe what you are looking for is not clear?

Answer (score 0):

Borrowed from Peter Norvig's pytudes to perform word segmentation.
Please try..

```
import re
import math
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter
from itertools   import permutations
from typing      import List, Tuple, Set, Dict, Callable

!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words.txt

Word = str    # We implement words as strings
cat = ''.join # Function to concatenate strings together


def tokens(text) -> List[Word]:
    """List all the word tokens (consecutive letters) in a text. Normalize to lowercase."""
    return re.findall('[a-z]+', text.lower()) 

TEXT = open('big.txt').read()
WORDS = tokens(TEXT)


class ProbabilityFunction:
    def __call__(self, outcome):
        """The probability of `outcome`."""
        if not hasattr(self, 'total'):
            self.total = sum(self.values())
        return self[outcome] / self.total
    
class Bag(Counter, ProbabilityFunction): """A bag of words."""
    

Pword = Bag(WORDS)


def Pwords(words: List[Word]) -> float:
    "Probability of a sequence of words, assuming each word is independent of others."
    return Π(Pword(w) for w in words)

def Π(nums) -> float:
    "Multiply the numbers together.  (Like `sum`, but with multiplication.)"
    result = 1
    for num in nums:
        result *= num
    return result

def splits(text, start=0, end=20) -> Tuple[str, str]:
    """Return a list of all (first, rest) pairs; start <= len(first) <= L."""
    return [(text[:i], text[i:]) 
            for i in range(start, min(len(text), end)+1)]

def segment(text) -> List[Word]:
    """Return a list of words that is the most probable segmentation of text."""
    if not text: 
        return []
    else:
        candidates = ([first] + segment(rest)
                      for (first, rest) in splits(text, 1))
        return max(candidates, key=Pwords)

strings = ['thatCreation', 'happeningso', 'comebecause']
[segment(string.lower()) for string in strings]
```

--2020-08-04 18:48:06--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words.txt
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 151.101.0.133, 151.101.64.133, 151.101.128.133, ...
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|151.101.0.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4863005 (4.6M) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘words.txt.2’

words.txt.2         100%[===================>]   4.64M   162KB/s    in 25s

2020-08-04 18:48:31 (192 KB/s) - ‘words.txt.2’ saved [4863005/4863005]

[['that', 'creation'], ['happening', 'so'], ['come', 'because']]

Comment: Thank you for helping, but it is not as clear to understand and giving so many errors, please help me out. Thank you - @pankaj giri

Comment: Sure.. what's the error you're getting @Rohan Patel

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def viterbi_segment(text):
    probs, lasts = [1.0], [0]
    for i in range(1, len(text) + 1):
        prob_k, k = max((probs[j] * word_prob(text[j:i]), j)
                    for j in range(max(0, i - max_word_length), i))
    probs.append(prob_k)
    lasts.append(k)
    words = []
    i = len(text)
    while 0 < i:
        words.append(text[lasts[i]:i])
        i = lasts[i]
    words.reverse()
    return words, probs[-1]
    

def word_prob(word): return dictionary[word] / total
def words(text): return re.findall('[a-z]+', text.lower())   
dictionary = Counter(words(open('big.txt').read()))
max_word_length = max(map(len, dictionary))  
total = float(sum(dictionary.values()))
l = ['thatCreation', 'happeningso', 'comebecause',]

for w in l:
    print(viterbi_segment(w.lower()))

O/p will be - 
(['that', 'creation'], 1.63869514118246e-07)
(['happening', 'so'], 1.1607123777400279e-07)
(['come', 'because'], 4.81658105705814e-07)
```

I got a solution to my problem from @Darius Bacon and for this, you need to make all strings a lowercase string.
Thank You Guys for your help.

Visit this link for download big.txt :
https://norvig.com/big.txt